# How to Prevent Video recording(record black video at recording) like hotstar app

Tags: android

in my application, Many videos are there but I need to prevent video recording just like hotstar

I tried this code but not work for me please help me

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* [mcve] showing how you used `FLAG_SECURE`, and please explain what "not work for me" means. How did you try "video recording"? What were the specific results? `FLAG_SECURE` works for screenshots and screencasts, on Android hardware, with some gaps, and only when used properly.

Comment: I add this code just like I provide in the description and someone asks a question like that in this platform but 'not working for me'. I need to prevent a third-party app that records the mobile screen. please check hotstar and record videos from hotstar for better understanding.